Can't make screenshot Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
I am trying to save screenshots in selenium to postgres database (with help of Django ORM)
I am using selenium==4.2.0 and Firefox 120.0
My error:
[2024-12-06 03:12:45,667: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Exception in check urls task: Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_1         |   File "/project/parser_app/celery_tasks.py", line 51, in check_urls
celery_1         |     parser.check_parsing_result(parsing_results)
celery_1         |   File "/project/parser_app/parser/common.py", line 238, in check_parsing_result
celery_1         |     body_elem.screenshot(image_path)
celery_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 725, in screenshot
celery_1         |     png = self.screenshot_as_png
celery_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 705, in screenshot_as_png
celery_1         |     return b64decode(self.screenshot_as_base64.encode('ascii'))
celery_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 693, in screenshot_as_base64
celery_1         |     return self._execute(Command.ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT)['value']
celery_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 773, in _execute
celery_1         |     return self._parent.execute(command, params)
celery_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
celery_1         |     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
celery_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
celery_1         |     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
celery_1         | selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://remote/content/shared/Capture.sys.mjs :: capture.canvas :: line 137"  data: no]

I understand that the reason is size of the page
My code:
def check_parsing_result(self, parsing_results: List[ParsingResult]) -> None:
        results_to_send = []
        for parsing_res in parsing_results:
            try:
                self.driver.get(parsing_res.url)
            execept:
                ... 
            finally:
                self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(-1) # set default timeout (inf)

                if int(os.getenv("SAVE_SCREENSHOT", 0)):
                    curr_time: str = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
                    file_name = f"scrin_{curr_time}.png"
                    image_path = f"{MEDIA_ROOT}/{file_name}"
                    body_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body') # intended to get image of full page
                    body_elem.screenshot(image_path) # error in this line



If you know what the issue is, what's your question?

you might not have a body element.  Have you tried just self.driver.screenshot_as_png(image_path) ?  (btw, page_load_timeout should be global and set at driver initialization...)

@JeffC how to fix it? I have screenshot all pages regardless of the size
